# Filter object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter through an array of objects and delete one of the object but keep the rest inside an array of objects but i keep returning either an array of arrays or i create nested objects. Is it possible to send in an array of objects and return and array of objects without that specific object? Below is the code I have been trying to work with.

```
      function deleteWorkout(workoutName) {
    
    const updatedArray = myWorkoutToDisplay.map((item) => item.newWorkToAdd.filter((workout) => workout.name !== workoutName))
    const objectArray = [{updatedArray}]
    const newWorkToAdd = objectArray.filter(e => e.length)
    const workouts = [{newWorkToAdd}]
    setMyWorkoutToDisplay(updatedArray)
  }
```

Comment: yo can you indent that code and provide more minimal code? i don't know what `myWorkoutToDisplay` is or `newWorkToAdd` is for certain.

Comment: This might be helpful.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdp0zrpKzIE&ab_channel=AkshaySaini

Comment: Sorry its a bit confusing because i tried so many different ways. workoutName is an array of objects i sent through the function and I'm trying to compare that using filter on myWorkoutDisplay with is also an array of objects but it has a key newWorkToAdd that i need to map first to get to the objects. It's an array then my newWorkToAdd then an array of objects.

Comment: You need to provide an example of your array of Objects and and the value to get a better answer we can't guess how your array looks

Comment: `"workoutToAdd": [
         {
          "name": "1\nKettlebell Slingshot (Kettlebell Around the World)",
          "image": "https://kettlebellsworkouts.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/01_kettlebell-slingshot.png"
         },
         {
          "name": "2\nKettlebell Halo",
          "image": "https://kettlebellsworkouts.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/02_kettlebell-halo.png"
         }]`

Comment: It is in state like that and in the function argument(workoutName) comes the name - "1\nKettlebell Slingshot (Kettlebell Around the World)"

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). I guess the easiest way to delete 1 object is like this:

```js
//let arr = arrayLike
//let objToDelete = whatever you want to delete
let newArr = arr.filter(obj => obj !== objToDelete)
```

`newArr` now has the array, without the deleted item. `arr` however still has it. To delete item by index, use this:

```js
//let arr = arrayLike
//let ind = index to delete
let newArr = arr.filter((_, index) => index !== ind)
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it didn't work. Im not sure if its because i had to map it first then use this.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn’t work"? Please clarify what happened instead of the expected result

Comment: It gave me back an array of arrays instead of an array of objects.

Comment: Can you give me what you are trying to filter so I can test it myself?

Comment: I copy and pasted it from the consol - newWorkToAdd: Array(1)
0:
image: "https://kettlebellsworkouts.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/02_kettlebell-halo.png"
name: "2\nKettlebell Halo"

Comment: When I call this line of code - const updatedArray = myWorkoutToDisplay.map((item) => item.newWorkToAdd.filter((workout) => workout.name !== workoutName)) - I am trying to selecect that and delete it from state in react but then it returns an array with the other object in there as an array and an empty array that used to be the object that I just deleted

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter` never returns anything in the new array that wasn't already there. Make sure your array has what you want in it